# google map marker clustering ad custom Infowindow Adapter how to set tag for clusterItem (marker)

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing, infowindow, markers

I'm facing a problem...
I am trying to make a map with markers on android, using google maps api, and i also managed to cluster them using **clusterManager**, everything works great so far, but the problem is when i try to make **custom Infowindow** for pins, i can get the title, snippet and position of the marker but the other info(like marker tag,id etc) it seems to be impossible.
i think that the problem is the ClusterItem it overrides only the title, snippet, and position.
Can someone help me with a workaround for  this problem?
 here is my code:
 this is where i get the markers from **firebase:**

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    places = database.getReference("Places");

    places.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            map.clear();
            mClusterManager.clearItems();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Double latitude = (Double) postSnapshot.child("Lat").getValue();
                Double longitude = (Double) postSnapshot.child("Long").getValue();
                String name = postSnapshot.getKey();
                String score = postSnapshot.child("score").getValue().toString();
                String photoUrl = postSnapshot.child("photoUrl").getValue().toString();
                String description = postSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
                MyMission mMission = new MyMission(latitude,longitude,name,score);

                mClusterManager.addItem(mMission);

                mClusterManager.cluster();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

here is the clusterItem class:

```
public class MyMission implements ClusterItem {

private LatLng mPosition;
private String mTitle;
private String mSnippet;

public MyMission(double lat, double lng) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

public MyMission(double lat, double lng, String title, String snippet) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mTitle = title;mSnippet = snippet;

}


@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}

@Override
public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

@Override
public String getSnippet() {
    return mSnippet;
}  
}
```

and this is the InfoWindowAdapter:

```
  public class CustomMarkerInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
private Activity context;

public CustomMarkerInfoWindow(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_info_window, null);
    TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.TitleTextView);
    TextView distance = view.findViewById(R.id.distanceValueTextView);
    TextView points = view.findViewById(R.id.pointsValueTextView);

    title.setText(marker.getTitle());
    distance.setText("2101");
    points.setText(marker.getSnippet());





    return view;
}
```

if it would be possible to change in the "InfowindowAdapter: the 
 "getInfoContents(Marker marker)" to something like: "getInfoContents(MyMission marker)"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this tutorial on cluster manager might help you as it has create a custom popup on a marker click which I think is what you are after.
[Work with ClusterManager](https://medium.com/@tonyshkurenko/work-with-clustermanager-bdf3d70fb0fd)

Comment: Thanks I managed to use the snippet and then separe the string using.split() ;